# Firefox WebExtension Content Script: TypeError: browser.runtime is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am attempting to create a firefox extension that has a background script with communication to a series of content scripts loaded on the website. My issue comes when trying to do anything with browser.runtime on the content script, it tells me it is undefined.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Script",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Test Script",

  "icons": {
      "48": "icon.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Trigger",
    "browser_style": false
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "main.js"
    ]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["/page_wrangler.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "*://www.example.com/*",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

All that is in my page_wrangler.js:

```
console.log("wrangled", browser.runtime);
```

As far as I can tell there is no specific permission I am missing.  I have been trying to figure this out for about half a week.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: My goal is to be able to call `browser.runtime.sendMessage()` to be able to call my background script and trigger some background work. This had been working for me, until it randomly stopped, I have been unable to trace down any one else having this kind of issue.

Comment: is `browser.runtime` supposed to be defined in a *content* script?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage

In the examples they call sendMessage from the content script, which is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: so what does `console.log("wrangled", browser.runtime);` output? `wrangled undefined` ?

Comment: Correct.  And if I try to call `browser.runtime.sendMessage` it errors with `browser.runtime is undefined`

Comment: What does your background_script look like? May you upload it?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] (i.e. including your *main.js*, or remove it from your *manifest.json*). Please provide information like: Firefox version, operating system, etc. `browser.runtime` should exist in a content script. Have you tried `chrome.runtime`?

Comment: Did you get any luck with that? I seem to have stumbled upon the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is not to use `web-ext` to test the addon, but instead to load it in normal browser section by going to `about:debugging` and using the "Load temporary addon" button.

Comment: If this is *not an answer*, please consider updating, deleting it or turning into a comment (you'll need enough reputation for that, though)